# How many database entries can I have before my application begins to become too slow?

Tags: android, database, search, dictionary

I have a question about database for a mobile application : I want to develop an application which will be a dictionary French-Kurdish. My idea is to fill my database with the word in French and his translation in Kurdish (a simple idea isn't it?). But it's a mobile application and I don't have any experience with databases so my question is : What is the limit of a database ? When I'm saying limit, I'm talking about the size of the database because the goal of the application is to be fast.

For my application, at minimum I have 1000 entries : Is that too much, or is it reasonable?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 0):

1000 entries is perfectly fine in terms of what SQLite can handle.

Here's [a discussion](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) on the limits of SQLite.

> The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2^64 (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable since the maximum database size of 140 terabytes will be reached first. A 140 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13 rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains very little data.

In terms of how large & fast your database will be, I think you also have nothing to worry about for 1k entries. If the speed of your queries became a problem it would be worth looking into optimisations, but I don't think you will need to given your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

To the previous answers, I believe that OP is not asking about the theoretical limit of how many database entries he can store, but rather, how many database entries he can store, before searching for a specific word, becomes slow, because of the sheer number of database entries to search through, in response to that, read up on search techniques for sqlite databases: [Best way to search sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175978/best-way-to-search-sqlite-databasehttp://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1955-how-to-use-full-text-search-in-sqlite/) and sqlite database caching and optimization: http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've some doubts about the limit of my database for the application but with your answers, I'm fine. To be more precisely, it's not 1000 entries in the same table but the number 1000 correspond to the sum of entries of all tables.

Comment: I am aware of that but what was your question about, the theoretical limit of tables/entries? or the speed? (just to clarify)

Comment: To clarify the situation, my question was about the theoretical limit of entries but for me (maybe I'm wrong) there is a link between the size of database (size means here the number of entries) and the speed.

Comment: Having more databases will not make your application slower generally(but it will make it larger) but when you "search the database" (which I assume is the primary function of your application as people will be translating, and your app will search the database for the inputted word, and the corresponding entry for the other language), the search will slow down, as the database entries increase. You should implement analytics and see which words are translated most, and in turn cache those, or look at some of the links that I posted about database optimization, as well as search optimization.

Comment: Thank you for these precisions. They help me a lot :)